# IIS 7 URL rewrite regular expression

Tags: regex, iis-7

Using IIS7 URL rewrite module, I am trying to get the value of a specific query string parameter, and if it exists I need to get the value of that parameter.

Example URL :

```
test.aspx?F5REDIRECTION&SearchType=HeaderSearch&hiddendims=&Keyword=tshirt&nkw=1&vsp=2
```

I need to check if "Keyword" parameter exists and I need to get the value "t-shirt".

If I test run this pattern :

```
^.*F5REDIRECTION&SearchType=Header.*Keyword=(.*)$
```

the result is `"tshirt&nkw=1&vsp=2"`

How do I get only "tshirt"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(?<=\?|&)Keyword=(.*?)(?=&|$)
```

Or if lookarounds aren't available:

```
(?:\?|&)Keyword=(.*?)(?:&|$)
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! although I did not get the part : (.*?)(?=&|$) where first it says take any charachter 0 or 1 of previous exp (.*?) but what does (?=&|$) do ? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi - Shibumi's comment is for you, I think. He's right, that site is a great reference for lookarounds and regex in general.